# How can I find the database in Android mobile?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

How can I find the database of the working application in android mobile which is connected with USB from the system.

Answer (score 0):

you're talking about real device `/data/data/<application-package-name>` is unaccessible. You must have root rights... for that see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GATh6iHgMzE) video

It can access from [ADB shell](http://androidblogger.blogspot.in/2009/06/tutorial-how-to-access-android-database.html)

Comment: How can I get the database.If am using MAC machine for android development @shylendra

Answer (score 0):

Install any root explorer on your device the goto /data/data/application package name /databases
in this path you can get the database of applicaiton . like in case of whatsapp the path for database will be /data/data/com.whatsapp/databases